# Sitecore 8.1 and xDB, Experience Analytics Tables Empty, Showing Errors

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I'm running Sitecore 8.1 Update 1 and am trying to get the basic built-in Experience Analytics working. However, I am getting an error on all the graphs such as

> The OnlineInteractionsByVisitsAndValuePerVisit graph cannot be
> displayed due to a server error. Contact your system administrator

After looking at the logs, I am getting errors such as the ones below:

```
15196 12:00:55 ERROR [Experience Analytics]: Could not find segment '786fba3a-4573-445e-a745-04e3ca5e48c1'
15196 12:00:55 ERROR [Experience Analytics]: Failed to construct segment from data row - Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.NotFoundException: Could not find segment '786fba3a-4573-445e-a745-04e3ca5e48c1'
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.LocalSegmentDefinitionService.GetSegmentTitle(Guid segmentId)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.LocalSegmentDefinitionService.CreateEntityFromReader(IDataRecord reader)
15196 12:00:55 ERROR [Experience Analytics]: Could not find segment 'dc0db760-b0f5-4690-b9eb-1bbf7a4f7bd1'
15196 12:00:55 ERROR [Experience Analytics]: Failed to construct segment from data row - Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.NotFoundException: Could not find segment 'dc0db760-b0f5-4690-b9eb-1bbf7a4f7bd1'
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.LocalSegmentDefinitionService.GetSegmentTitle(Guid segmentId)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.LocalSegmentDefinitionService.CreateEntityFromReader(IDataRecord reader)
15196 12:17:56 INFO  [Experience Analytics]: Reduce agent found zero segments to process
```

I have tried to follow the common steps, such as the ones below and I also tried the ones suggested by Sitecore (https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445) but nothing resolved the problem. The only thing, I can think of is maybe MongoDB doesn't have access to the reporting DB in SQL, but I didn't see anything called out that it needed special permissions.

- redeploy segments setting the deploy date
  to a much earlier time (a year ago)
- rebuilding the reporting database
- cleared browser cache
- checked the `MongoDB` shows data (and it correctly shows page visits in interactions collection)
- checked that my reporting DB does contain segments.

Comment: Can you find the items `dc0db760-b0f5-4690-b9eb-1bbf7a4f7bd1` and `786fba3a-4573-445e-a745-04e3ca5e48c1` in the master database?

Comment: Seems like the marketing segments that are in the analytics dB are somehow not the right ones (as in, matching with master), or are not accessible perhaps. I realise you said you checked this, but that is what the error indicates.

Comment: Is it possible for you to rebuild reporting database using /sitecore/admin/RebuildReportingDB.aspx?

Comment: Yes, those two segments show up in the reporting database segments table and I am able to rebuiling the reporting database.

Comment: @Chris Were you able to get past this?

Answer (score 0):

The error messages indicate that Sitecore Experience Analytics is encountering difficulties finding or constructing segments with specific GUIDs. Here are steps you can take to address this issue:

**Verify Segment Existence:**

Check if the segments with the mentioned GUIDs ('**786fba3a-4573-445e-a745-04e3ca5e48c1**' and '**dc0db760-b0f5-4690-b9eb-1bbf7a4f7bd1**') actually exist in your Sitecore instance.

Navigate to the Marketing Control Panel in Sitecore, go to the 'Segments' tab, and verify the presence of these segments.

**Rebuild Reporting Database and Segments:**

Rebuilding the reporting database is a good step, but also ensure that the segments are correctly processed and stored in the reporting database.

You might want to clear the existing segments from the reporting database and then rebuild to ensure a clean slate.

**Check Deploy Date for Segments:**

Ensure that the segments have a deploy date set, and it is not set to a future date. Experience Analytics relies on the deploy date to determine when segments become active.

**Review MongoDB Access:**

Verify that MongoDB has proper access to the reporting database in SQL Server. Ensure that the MongoDB connection string in the **ConnectionStrings.config** file includes the correct credentials for accessing the reporting database.

By going through these steps, you should be able to identify and resolve the issue with the missing or misconfigured segments in Sitecore Experience Analytics.